# Uploading image to FB staging server using jssdk returns error

Tags: facebook

I'm creating FB App that upload and post images to user's wall, and I'm stuck at this point. I would like to upload images on FB staging server, because my server is too small. When I try to post image with this code

```js
FB.api('/me/staging_resources?access_token='+access_token, 'post', {file: file_uri}, function(response) {
        if (!response) {
       alert('Error occurred.');
     } else if (response.error) {
       console.log('Error: ' + response.error.message);
     } else {
       console.log('File uri is ' + response.uri );
       file_uri = response.uri;
     }
    });
```

where file_uri is variable that contain https address to the image, I constantly receive error `"(#100) Invalid file. Expected file of one of the following types: image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/png"`. I tested also from Graph API Explorer, same error.
I tried everything, to put url to file that generate image, to put direct url to the image, http, https, some image from other site... always the same.
Does anyone have any help for me, maybe I am missing something?

Thanks in advance, 
Nikola

**Edit - Solution**

Thanks again to Jason, I succeeded to get image, if anyone ran into this problem, solution is to make separate curl file that calls `https://graph.facebook.com/me/staging_resources` with url of the image and access token, and then in js file make a simple call

```
$.get('/curl.php?url='+image_url+'&access_token='+access_token,function(response){
        console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/#staging), the file parameter needs to be actually file data (as in a `enctype='multipart/form-data'` HTTP POST).  As an example they show posting via curl:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://graph.facebook.com/me/staging_resources \
  -F "file=@images/prawn-curry-1.jpg" \
  -F "access_token=$USER_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

It cannot take a URI that resolves to a file (you have to preform the fetch)

Comment: Thanks for answer Jason!
I get the general principle now... but I am not an expert in js, do you have some idea how can I make that with jssdk?

Comment: That is a lot trickier. It would involve using a really new feature of HTML5 called [FormData](http://caniuse.com/xhr2) (from the [File API](http://caniuse.com/fileapi))